# Let $F_n$, $G_n$ and $H_n$, Show that $H_n$ can be obtained by multiplying $F_n$ by $G_n$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $F_n$, $G_n$ and $H_n$ be the $n^{th}$ Taylor polynomial about $x_0$ of $f$,$g$ and their product $h=fg$. Show that $H_n$ can be obtained by multiplying $F_n$ by $G_n$ and retaining only the powers of $x-x_0$ through the $n^{th}$ .

1. I found out about the Leibniz's rule:

$$(fg)^{n}(x_0) = \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!} f^{(k)}(x_0) g^{(n-k)}(x_0)
$$
 I would do here a proof by induction

2. Regarding the second part of the question: "and retaining only the powers of $x-x_0$ through the $n^{th}$"

We know that $R_f(x)=o((x-x_0)^n)$, $R_{g}(x)=o((x-x_0)^n)$, $R_h=R_{fg}=o((x-x_0)^n)$ all three being polynomials of degree n, all identically 0. Therefore they do retain the powers of $(x-x_0)$ through the $n^{th}$.

Am i going in the right direction? is there a better approach? Hint?

Comment: Your approach is perfect. +1 the second point is not relevant here by the way and perhaps it does not make too much sense.

Comment: @ParamanandSingh thx for the input. I am not sure what it is meant by "retaining only the power of $(x-x_0)$ through the $n^{th}$." what understanding do you have from this quote?

Comment: Note that $F_n, G_n$ are polynomials of degree $n$ and when you multiply them you get a polynomial of degree $2n$. Out of this polynomial of degree $2n$ you need to drop/discard all the terms with degree greater than $n$ and retain terms only terms only upto $n$'th power of $(x-x_{0})$. You need to prove that the resulting polynomial is $H_n$.